# How to edit/add/update datagridview directly on Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am making a Windows Forms App that manages a hotel. It has Client, Room, Occupancy classes. Client and Rooms have an ArrayList that is populated at runtime from a .txt file that is then displayed in a clientListView and a roomDataGridView.

As such, I have this line of code to populate the roomsDGV:

```
roomsDGV.DataSource = roomsArrayList;
```

With the roomsDGV, I'm trying to add new Rows by clicking on the roomsDGV, like when it is NOT databound. I am also trying to edit the rows and save it to txt file after editing or as I'm editing. I can post more code as necessary but I'm not sure if showing more code will help at the current moment. In the end, I'm trying for a functionality so that I can highlight a client in the list and click on one of the rows in roomsDGV and assign that clientID to that room or any sort of way like that.

On load, the datagridview is loaded and formatted correctly from the arrayList but I seem to be having this problem of being able to edit the datagridview. It gives me this error when I click on one of the rows:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index -1 does not have a value.'
```

This stems from  Application.Run(new HotelManager());

Here is the form:

```
public partial class HotelManager : Form
{
    // VARIABLES
    string clientID;
    // FILEPATHS
    string clientsTxt = "Clients.txt";
    string occupanciesTxt = "Occupancies.txt";
    string roomsTxt = "Rooms.txt";
    string clientsDat = "Clients.dat";

    // ARRAYLIST FOR ROOMS and CLIENTS
    ArrayList roomsArrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList clientsArrayList = new ArrayList();

    //STACKS AND QUEUES INIT
    // Load occupancies into stack > pop
    Stack roomStack = new Stack();
    Queue vacancyQueue = new Queue();

    // RANDOM for ID
    private readonly Random rand = new Random();

    public HotelManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HotelManager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        roomsDGV.DataSource = roomsArrayList;
        // LOAD clients
        // LoadClients();
        RefreshClientList();
        // LOAD rooms
        LoadRooms();
    }
    private void NewClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddClient();
    }
    private void checkInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clientID = clientList.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(occupanciesTxt);
        foreach (string s in text)
        {
            if (s.Contains(clientID))
            {
                var replace = s;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                replace = replace.Replace("false", "true");
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(occupanciesTxt, text);
    }

    // METHODS

    private void AddClient()
    {
        //COLLECT DATA > CREATE NEW client > SHOW IN **PROGRAM/DataGridView** > add to clients file
        // ID GENERATION > CHECKS AGAINST clientsTXT
        clientID = rand.Next(0, 999999).ToString();
        if (File.ReadLines(clientsTxt).Contains(clientID))
        {
            clientID = rand.Next(0, 999999).ToString();
        }
        Client client = new Client(clientID, firstNameBox.Text, lastNameBox.Text);
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNumBox.Text))
            {
                client.PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumBox.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressBox.Text))
            {
                client.Address = addressBox.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please use the correct format!");
            throw;
        }
        clientsArrayList.Add(client);
        using (StreamWriter file =
        new StreamWriter("Clients.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(client.ToString());
        }
        RefreshClientList();
        // TEST CODE // SERIALIZATION TO .DAT
        SerializeClientData(client);
    }
    private void LoadClients()
    {
        // LOADS arrayList FROM .txt FILE
        List<string> clientList = File.ReadAllLines(clientsTxt).ToList();
        foreach (var c in clientList)
        {
            Client client = new Client(c);
            clientsArrayList.Add(client);
        }
    }

    private void LoadRooms()
    {
        List<string> roomsList = File.ReadAllLines(roomsTxt).ToList();
        foreach (var r in roomsList)
        {
            var roomDetails = r.Split('|');
            if (r.Contains("BASIC"))
            {
                BasicRoom basic = new BasicRoom();
                basic.RoomNumber = roomDetails[0];
                basic.NumberOfBeds = Convert.ToInt32(roomDetails[1]);
                basic.Balcony = Convert.ToBoolean(roomDetails[2]);
                basic.DownForRepair = Convert.ToBoolean(roomDetails[3]);
                basic.Smoking = Convert.ToBoolean(roomDetails[4]);
                roomsArrayList.Add(basic);

            }
            else if (r.Contains("SUITE"))
            {
                Suite suite = new Suite();
                suite.RoomNumber = roomDetails[0];
                suite.NumberOfBeds = Convert.ToInt32(roomDetails[1]);
                suite.Balcony = Convert.ToBoolean(roomDetails[2]);
                suite.DownForRepair = Convert.ToBoolean(roomDetails[3]);
                suite.NumberOfRooms = Convert.ToInt32(roomDetails[4]);
                roomsArrayList.Add(suite);
            }
        }
        roomStack = new Stack(roomsArrayList);
        foreach (var item in roomStack)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    private void RoomsDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void RoomsDGV_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

So far I've looked through all the properties but I can't seem to find the right one. I know I can add/use comboboxes and etc to add a new item into the arrayList instead but I'm trying for datagridview functionality

I expect to edit and add rows to the DGV, but something in the designer is preventing me?
Here is the DGV, and clicking on any of the rows breaks it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwf0L.jpg

Comment: An arraylist is almost always the wrong choice - especially here.  if you used a `List<T>` or a `DataTable` you could preserve the type.  A DGV with a DataTable and DataAdpater can very easily update the db.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason I use an arrayList is because it was a requirement, but I can go through different ways as long as I use an arrayList to display the rooms and their properties. Should I reference the arrayList to a datatable? and if so, would iterating through the arrayList and adding it one by one to the datable the correct way?

Comment: There is not enough info, to help. Adding and editing row/cells in a grid is fairly straight forward. “How” this is done is usually related to “how” the data is added to the grid. You need to show the code that creates the `roomsArrayList` variable and if there is a cell click event, then it would help to see that. There are two many different questions in this one question. Give enough info to reproduce the problem or speculation is all you may get.

Answer (score 0):

check this

[Insert, Update, Delete with DataGridView Control in C# (Windows Application) | A Rahim Khan's Blog](https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/insert-update-delete-with-datagridview-control-in-c-windows-applica)

[Insert, Update and Delete Records in a C# DataGridView](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/insert-update-and-delete-record-in-datagridview-C-Sharp/)

Good Luck

Comment: With the second link, that's the method of doing it by using other controls. I was wondering if you can do it in datagridview natively? I have a few properties that are booleans and on the DGV they appear as checkmarks, I was hoping to be able to edit the rows by checking or unchecking the cell.